# Minecraft Server 1.7.2 Not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I recently got a server up and working on my computer for 1.6.4 - it was a lot of confusion and problems, but in the end I have my router set up for port forwarding on :25565, and I have my firewall settings letting Minecraft, my 1.6.4 server, and Java SE Binary through (although I don't know if I needed all of those). However, with the 1.7.2 update, my server isn't working at all anymore. I tried an Open Port Check Tool to see if it's a problem with the other computer, but it says my port is closed on :25565.

So, I have two questions:
1) If I have the Minecraft server (from the Minecraft website), but for 1.6.4, will it update to 1.7.2 on its own, or do I need to download the server 1.7.2 on the website?
2) Why isn't my server working?

Answer (score 6):

The server is still running 1.6.4, but your client is 1.7.2. This mismatch means that you won't be able to connect to your server until you either upgrade the server, or revert to an older client.

Unfortunately the server does not update automatically, you need to update the server manually. Go to the Minecraft website and download the new server software for 1.7.2.